# Data reading from .ods format file,Code is not working

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, ods

I have written this code, but not getting any output:

```
require_once 'SpreadsheetReaderFactory.php';

$spreadsheetsFilePath = 'data.ods';
$reader = SpreadsheetReaderFactory::reader($spreadsheetsFilePath);

$sheets = $reader->read($spreadsheetsFilePath);

print_r($sheets);
```

Comment: Assuming that you're using `https://github.com/xhook/php-spreadsheetreader` then it doesn't support OASIS-format `.ods` files, just csv and BIFF-format `.xls` files

Comment: then what is solution? @Mark

Comment: The solution is to use a Reader library that does support OASIS format files, such as my own [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) library